# Sample for REST API using Location and JSON

Tags: ktor

The title already says what I'm trying to do in a nutshell: implement a simple REST API that uses ktor's Location feature and accepts requests with JSON as payload.
Let's say that I want to have a resource "books" that is available under the URI /books. A get request should return a list of available books, a post request with data for a new book should create a new book and return a redirect to the newly created book. My implementation looks like this:

```
@Location ("/books") data class BookRequest(val title: String = "" )

fun Application.bookModule() {
    routing {
        get<BookRequest> {
            val books = bookHandler.listBooks()
            //generate HTML from books and respond
        }
        post<BookRequest> {
            val request = call.receive<BookRequest>()
            //create a new book resource from the data in request
            //and respond with redirect to new book
         }
}
```

The get request works as intended but when I try to POST a new book using curl like this

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
   --data '{"title":"Hitchhiker"}' \
   http://localhost:8080/books
```

the content of the title attribute of the request is empty.

Does anyone have a pointer to a working example using Locations with POST and JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [ContentNegotiation](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html) plugin for deserializing JSON data to a `BookRequest` object and if you use [kotlinx.serialization](https://ktor.io/docs/kotlin-serialization.html) then mark the `BookRequest` class with `Serializable` annotation. Here is the full example:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.features.*
import io.ktor.locations.*
import io.ktor.locations.post
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.serialization.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        install(Locations)
        routing {
            post<BookRequest> {
                val r = call.receive<BookRequest>()
                call.respondText { r.title }
            }
        }
    }.start()
}

@Location("/books")
@Serializable
data class BookRequest(val title: String = "")
```

Comment: Aleksei, thanks for the example. Working now.